# Webpack scss Unexpected character '@'

Tags: webpack, sass

This is my webpack.config.js

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
      rules: 
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scss'),
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']

                })
             }

    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: './dist/bundle.css',
        }),
    ],
```

And i got this error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (4:0)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    > @import 'base/grid';
```

In css-loader docs written that it translate @import, so why do i got this error?

Comment: Have you installed sass-loader ( `npm i -D sass-loader` ) ?